# Looping through table to find value from a textbox

Tags: sql, vba, forms, loops, ms-access

I'm trying to loop through a column inside a table from a form in Access to find out whether a "Case Name" already exists or not, and if it does not, then add the new record to the table. I want the criteria to be based on the input value of a text box. The good news is I have figured out how to add a new record to the table with the code below. I'm just stuck on how to loop through a table to find out if a record already exists. Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub SaveNewCase_Click()

If Me.txtNewCaseName.Value <> "Null" And Me.txtCaseDepth.Value <> "Null" And Me.txtCaseHeight2.Value <> "Null" And Me.txtCaseWeight.Value <> "Null" And Me.txtCaseWidth <> "Null" And Me.cboCaseCategory.Value <> "Null" Then
    'I think the loop should go here, but not sure'
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblCases(CaseName, CaseWidth, CaseHeight, CaseCasters, CaseWeight, CaseDepth, CaseCategory) " & _
        " VALUES ('" & Me.txtNewCaseName & "'," & Me.txtCaseWidth & "," & Me.txtCaseHeight2 & ",'" & Me.chkboxCasters & "'," & Me.txtCaseWeight & "," & Me.txtCaseDepth & ",'" & Me.cboCaseCategory & "')"
Else
    MsgBox "Please enter all new case criteria."
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Don't need a loop. Use DCount.

Comment: If you make`CaseName`the primary key or an unique index, you don't have to worry anymore, because error raises on dupe insert/update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, **use parameters**!

Concatenating values supplied by a user directly into your SQL statement exposes your to [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/), either intentional (i.e. users entering their own SQL statements to sabotage your database) or unintentional (e.g. users entering values containing apostrophes or other SQL delimiters).

Instead, represent each of the field values with a parameter, for example:

```vb
With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef _
    ( _
        "", _
        "insert into " & _
        "tblcases (casename,  casewidth,  caseheight,  casecasters,  caseweight,  casedepth,  casecategory) " & _
        "values  (@casename, @casewidth, @caseheight, @casecasters, @caseweight, @casedepth, @casecategory) " _
    )
    .Parameters("@casename") = txtNewCaseName
    .Parameters("@casewidth") = txtCaseWidth
    .Parameters("@caseheight") = txtCaseHeight2
    .Parameters("@casecasters") = chkboxCasters
    .Parameters("@caseweight") = txtCaseWeight
    .Parameters("@casedepth") = txtCaseDepth
    .Parameters("@casecategory") = cboCaseCategory
    .Execute
End With
```

Since the value of each form control is fed directly to the parameter within the SQL statement, the value will always be interpreted as a literal and cannot form part of the SQL statement itself.

Furthermore, you don't have to worry about surrounding your string values with single or double quotes, and you don't have to worry about formatting date values - the data is used in its native form.

---

Where testing for an existing value is concerned, you can either use a domain aggregate function, such as [`DLookup`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/dlookup-function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937), or you could use a SQL `select` statement and test that no records are returned, e.g.:

```vb
Dim flg As Boolean
With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef _
    ( _
        "", _
        "select * from tblcases where " & _
        "casename     = @casename    and " & _
        "casewidth    = @casewidth   and " & _
        "caseheight   = @caseheight  and " & _
        "casecasters  = @casecasters and " & _
        "caseweight   = @caseweight  and " & _
        "casedepth    = @casedepth   and " & _
        "casecategory = @casecategory " _
    )
    .Parameters("@casename") = txtNewCaseName
    .Parameters("@casewidth") = txtCaseWidth
    .Parameters("@caseheight") = txtCaseHeight2
    .Parameters("@casecasters") = chkboxCasters
    .Parameters("@caseweight") = txtCaseWeight
    .Parameters("@casedepth") = txtCaseDepth
    .Parameters("@casecategory") = cboCaseCategory
    With .OpenRecordset
        flg = .EOF
        .Close
    End With
End With

If flg Then
    ' Add new record
Else
    ' Record already exists
End If
```

---

Finally, you're currently testing the values of your form controls against the literal string `"Null"`, which will only be validated if the user has entered the value `Null` into the control, not if the control is blank.

Instead, you should use the VBA [`IsNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnull-function) function to check whether a variable holds a Null value.

Comment: Consider adding my comment on using an unique index, as that prevents dupes no matter where they are tried to add.